# How to take out text from the following HTML TEXT using HTMLParser in Python?

Tags: python

Given below is the extract from html file. I want to get only the text part from it using HTMLParser.

```
<html>
    <div class="js-tweet-text-container">
        <p class="TweetTextSize js-tweet-text tweet-text" data-aria-label-part=
        "0" lang="en"><a class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav"
        data-mentioned-user-id="119293693" dir="ltr" href=
        "/attrc"><s>@</s><b><strong>attrc</strong></b></a> as soon as <a class=
        "twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" data-mentioned-user-id="352507986"
        dir="ltr" href="/PoppySeedPlehzr"><s>@</s><b>PoppySeedPlehzr</b></a>
        gets some <a class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav"
        data-query-source="hashtag_click" dir="ltr" href=
        "/hashtag/osquery?src=hash"><s>#</s><b>osquery</b></a> tables going for
        Windows, that would be a good first use case for us :)</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

I want the following output from above:

```
@attrc as soon as poppyseedplehzr gets some osquery tables going for
windows,that would be a good first use case for us.
```

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and ask yourself: can someone without prior knowledge of your problem and its context understand what you're asking?

Comment: What have you tried? How does it differ from the expected output? Let's see your code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead. First let's install it:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then our code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
    <div class="js-tweet-text-container">
        <p class="TweetTextSize js-tweet-text tweet-text" data-aria-label-part=
        "0" lang="en"><a class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav"
        data-mentioned-user-id="119293693" dir="ltr" href=
        "/attrc"><s>@</s><b><strong>attrc</strong></b></a> as soon as <a class=
        "twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" data-mentioned-user-id="352507986"
        dir="ltr" href="/PoppySeedPlehzr"><s>@</s><b>PoppySeedPlehzr</b></a>
        gets some <a class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav"
        data-query-source="hashtag_click" dir="ltr" href=
        "/hashtag/osquery?src=hash"><s>#</s><b>osquery</b></a> tables going for
        Windows, that would be a good first use case for us :)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="js-tweet-text-container">
        <p class="TweetTextSize js-tweet-text tweet-text" data-aria-label-part=
        "0" lang="en"><a class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav"
        data-mentioned-user-id="119293693" dir="ltr" href=
        "/attrc"><s>@</s><b><strong>attrc</strong></b></a> as soon as <a class=
        "twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" data-mentioned-user-id="352507986"
        dir="ltr" href="/PoppySeedPlehzr"><s>@</s><b>PoppySeedPlehzr</b></a>
        gets some <a class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav"
        data-query-source="hashtag_click" dir="ltr" href=
        "/hashtag/osquery?src=hash"><s>#</s><b>osquery</b></a> tables going for
        Windows, that would be a good first use case for us :)</p>
    </div>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for tweet in soup.find_all('p', class_="tweet-text"):
    print ' '.join([line.strip() for line in tweet.get_text().splitlines()])
```

This gives us:

```
@attrc as soon as @PoppySeedPlehzr gets some #osquery tables going for Windows, that would be a good first use case for us :)
@attrc as soon as @PoppySeedPlehzr gets some #osquery tables going for Windows, that would be a good first use case for us :)
```

Comment: I second the recommendation of BeautifulSoup.